# CAn we use search for value added in plone form gen using DataContentAdapter

Tags: python, plone

I have created a form using PloneFormGen in Plone 4.1. I have used DataContentAdapter to trigger workflows on the data. How can I search for values submitted via this form using Plone's default LiveSearch ?

Comment: Personal curiosity, but what is your first language?

Comment: No no, not at all. It's just I've noticed your use of "we". I've seen the same usage many times on this site and I was just curious. It's perfectly good english.

Comment: d2c should add a feature to be able to set a field as indexable via "SearchableText" indexer. That'd hit your use case perfectly I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've to index them. This thread can help a lot:

http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Can-you-add-a-field-introduced-by-schemaextender-as-a-catalog-column-td3937077.html

Basically, you can use http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.indexer to index fields generated by schemaextender (which is used by DataContentAdapter, from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/uwosh.pfg.d2c)